# How to create a function to calculate days of years?

Tags: python

I want to create function to calculate the days of year as code below. While the python throw out typeError: 'int'object is not callable. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

def DaysOfYear(year, month, day):

```
import datetime

dt=datetime.datetime(year,month, day, 0, 0)
tt=dt.timetuple().tm_yday()
```

DaysOfYear(2012, 11, 7)

The below code with specific days works. But I need to call function with variable (year, month,day) What should I do to revise the above code?

from datetime import date
dt=date(2012,11,7)
print(dt.timetuple().tm_yday)

Comment: `tt=dt.timetuple().tm_yday` I guess ... maybe

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: If you need to get the "the days of year" you need a function with this signature: def days_in_year(year:int). It just returns 365 for regular years and 366 for leap years. Your question, and the examples in it, are so confused/confusing that is probably impossible to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implements what the others stated and works:

```
def DaysOfYear(year, month, day):
    import datetime
    dt=datetime.datetime(year,month, day, 0, 0)
    tt=dt.timetuple().tm_yday
    return tt

print( DaysOfYear(2011,11,1) )
```

Comment: It finally works, Thanks so much! NO parenthesis after .tm_yday, and need "return"

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
tt=dt.timetuple().tm_yday()
```

by

```
dt.timetuple().tm_yday
```

`tm_yday` is an attribute (with value `int`, being non-callable since its not a function) in `datetime.timetuple()` of type `time.struct_time`.

```
>>> dt=datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0)
>>> dt.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=24, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=358, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: from datetime import date
dt=date(2012,11,7)
print(dt.timetuple().tm_yday)       this one works, but I need to call function with variable , year, month, day. How to do?